# First day of a month

Tags: java

For a HOMEWORK assignment, I have to make a full year calendar. I managed to get the right format etc, but the months always start on a sunday. I have to add some things to make it work that the month starts on the right day of the week.

**Can someone maybe explain, how I calculate (and implement this)on which day of the week a month starts?** It is used in the function `showYear`.

The programming language is Java.

*Some limitations: I am not allowed to use predefined classes Calendar or Date etc. And I am not allowed to use arrays.*

Here is my code till now:

```
package..;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Easter {
 public static void main(String[] arguments) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the year:");
  int year = scanner.nextInt();
  showYear(year);
  scanner.close();
 }

 static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 100 == 0)
   year = year / 100;
  if (year % 4 == 0)
   return true;
  return false;
 }

 static int numberOfDaysInMonth(int year, Month month) //this function uses a Class that is made by my professor. But this is not relevant for my question//
 {
  switch (month) {
   case APRIL:
   case JUNE:
   case SEPTEMBER:
   case NOVEMBER:
    return 30;
   case FEBRUARY:
    if (isLeapYear(year))
     return 29;
    return 28;
   default:
    return 31;
  }
 }
 static void showYear(int year) {
  System.out.println(year);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("       " + Month.month(i));
   System.out.println(" S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
   // String firstWeek="";
   // how to calculate what day the month starts?
   // System.out.print(firstWeek);
   int dayOfMonth = 1;
   while (dayOfMonth <= numberOfDaysInMonth(year, Month.month(i))) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 7 && (dayOfMonth <= numberOfDaysInMonth(year, Month.month(i))); k++) {
     System.out.printf("%2d ", dayOfMonth);
     dayOfMonth++;
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is my question a bit clear?

Comment: You need a reference, a first Monday -of Year, Decade, Century, Age, etc.- just pick one. So you can compute the first day/monday of Year.

Comment: For a homework assignment I would just harcode the day of week of January 1 and then have each subsequent month start the day after the previous month ended. As an aside: *I am not allowed to use predefined classes Calendar or Date*. You wouldn’t want that anyway, those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. If `LocalDate`, the modern class for a date, had been allowed, you would have wanted to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In the gregorian calendar, a year is a leap year if the year is dividable by 4, not by 100, or by 400:

```
(year%4 == 0) && ((year%100 != 0) || (year%400 == 0)).
```

That will give you the the number of days in a year (365, or 366 for a leap year).

Your can compute the number of days from the beginning of (virtual) year 0:

```
yearStart = 365*year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400
```

The number of days from the beginning of the year to the beginning of the month is:

```
0 if month == 1
0+31 if month == 2
0+31+x if month == 3(where x is either 28 or 29 days depending on the year)
0+31+x+31 if month == 4
etc...
```

Now, to avoid using the number of days in the month of February (that is not constant) in the computation, you can make the year start in March:

```
int monthIndex;
if (month < 3) {
    --year;
    monthIndex = month + 12 - 3;
} else {
    monthIndex = month - 3;
}
```

Now you can store the number of days from the beginning of the year to the beginning of the month:

```
static final int[] MONTH_START = {
    0, // March
    31, // April
    31+30, // May
    31+30+31, // June
    31+30+31+30, // Jully
    31+30+31+30+31, // August
    31+30+31+30+31+31, // September
    31+30+31+30+31+31+30, // October
    31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31, // November
    31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30, // December
    31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30+31, // January
    31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30+31+31, // February
};
```

You just need to add the day of the month minus 1.

Putting it all together:

```
public static int days(int year, int month, int day) {
    int monthIndex;
    if (month < 3) {
        --year;
        monthIndex = month + 12 - 3;
    } else {
        monthIndex = month - 3;
    }
    int yearStart = 365*year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400;
    return yearStart + MONTH_START[monthIndex] + day-1;
}
```

This gives you the number of days from some reference date, to the given date. For instance, for the first of October 2019, you get 737638, and you know that this is a Tuesday. 737638 % 7 gives 6, so you would get a 4 for a sunday. You can now write a method giving you the day of the week:

```
public static int dayOfWeek(int year, int month, int day) {
    return (days(year, month, day)-4)%7;
}
```

It returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on...